# Save the new value of a variable whenever it changes

Tags: c++, vector, status

I'm using C++ on Visual Studio 2015. I want to check if the status variable changes during these lines. if everything is OK status always returns 0 else -1.
My problem here is that I'm checking **only on the last status** variable.
How can I know if any of status got -1 ?

```
int function1(ATF *cm33) {

int status;
uint32_t val;

status = cm33->readData32(SAU_CTRL_Mv8, &val);
status = cm33->writeData32(SAU_CTRL_Mv8, 0x3);
status = cm33->readData32(SAU_CTRL_Mv8, &val);

return status;  }
```

Comment: Please decide which language you are writing in before you start writing.

Comment: That's not valid C# syntax and therefore won't compile.

Comment: What about checking the return value after each function call? Using different variables? Depending on your use case you might skip following function calls in case of error or simply accumulate errors of the calls.

Comment: not clear what the problem is. why not `if (status == 1) { ...} else if (status == 0) { ..}` ? of course after each assignment to status

Comment: Sorry for not including the language I'm using. in fact it is C++ on Visual Studio 2015. I've modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the value of `-1` to signify that *any* of the statuses were non-zero then use

```
int status = 0;
```

followed by

```
status |= cm33->readData32(SAU_CTRL_Mv8, &val);
status |= cm33->writeData32(SAU_CTRL_Mv8, 0x3);
status |= cm33->readData32(SAU_CTRL_Mv8, &val);
```

This has the advantage of *only* returning `0` if every status was `0`. Adding the values just *might* push the program into an undefined state if the possible status values were to change in some way. Don't write it in one expression of the form `status = a | b | c;` since the behaviour of the program would then be undefined due to the (suspected) unsequenced writes to `val` via the pointers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this what I was looking for. at the end I will check on the last status value, if it is 0 then all the previous status were 0, else at least one of them was non-null.